# Install of Medusa.js (on MacOS Catalina) hanging for a 10 hours, what can I check or try?

Tags: medusajs, medusa

I am attempting to install Medusa on MacOS (Catalina). I installed the dependencies listed in the documentation and then used `npx create-medusa-app@latest` to begin the install. Terminal shows project was built, admin user created and project prepared roughly ten hours ago, but the process has not finished in Terminal and nothing has opened in my browser. There was a message as follows:
`[medusa-config] ⚠️ redis_url not found. A fake redis instance will be used.`
followed by some brief activity which stopped with `webpack 5.89.0 compiled successfully in 28728 ms` and hangs.

What might I do to troubleshoot or fix this issue, or is it really plausible it would take this long? So far, I have not found any troubleshooting steps for this particular issue in the documentation or online.